# Prepend leading zeros to each line of a file

Tags: string, awk, numeric, zero-padding

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1:line1
14:line2
135:line3
15:line4
```

I need to prepend leading zeros to each line to make it look like this:

```
00001:line1
00014:line2
00135:line3
00015:line4
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Linux?

I have tried using

```
awk '{printf "%05d:%s\n", FNR, $0}' file
```

but this outputted:

```
00001:1:line1
00002:14:line2
00003:135:line3
00004:15:line4
```

I should note I did not write this command, I got it from Google and don't really understand how it works

Comment: It's always good to provide truly representative sample input, not just `line1`, etc. so you can show us realistic examples of your input that include rainy day cases such as `:`s in that part of the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways, one way is to use `awk`

```bash
awk -F":" '{OFS=FS; $1 = sprintf("%05d", $1); print}' "${filename}"
```

To break it down:

- `-F":"` set the field seperator to ":", `awk` will split the lines into columns for each `:`.
- `OFS=FS` set the output field separator to the field separator, this essentially puts ":" back into each line when we output it.
- `$1 = sprintf("%05d", $1)` set the first column, `$1`, to be itself padded with 0's and of length 5.
- `print` print the line.

Comment: This was in response to the original, unedited, question, which didn't mention awk and used printf instead. Will leave here anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{p=index($0,":"); printf "%05d%s\n", substr($0,1,p-1), substr($0,p)}' file
00001:line1
00014:line2
00135:line3
00015:line4
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding one more way of doing it in `awk`. Setting field separator and output field separator as `:` and adding spaces to 1st field to make it 5 only as per need, then substituting each space with `0`.

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=':' '{$1=sprintf("%5s",$1);gsub(/ /,"0",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} 
{$1=sprintf("%05d", $1)} 1' file
```

Prints:

```
00001:line1
00014:line2
00135:line3
00015:line4
```

---

From comments, a cool version:

```
awk '$1=sprintf("%05d", $1)' FS=: OFS=: file
# same
```

Comment: or even more golfed `awk '$1=sprintf("%05d",$1)' FS=: OFS=:`

Comment: @dawg @Thor : `echo '9992315351235323253252317:line9' | gawk '$1=sprintf("%05d", $1)' FS=: OFS=:` ====> `9992315351235322445824000:line9`

Answer (score 3):

check it out too (thnx to @EdMorton)

```
awk -F':' '{
    p = index($0, ":")
    tag = substr($0, 1, p-1)
    val = substr($0, p+1) 
    # or tag=val=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",tag); sub(/[^:]+:/,"",val)
    printf "%05d:%s\n", tag, val
}' input.txt
```

Any time you have `tag:value` pairs if you don't KNOW and completely control exactly which chars value can contain it's safer to do `p=index($0,":"); tag=substr($0,1,p-1); val=substr($0,p+1)` or `tag=val=$0; sub(/:.*/,"",tag); sub(/[^:]+:/,"",val)` or similar than `tag=$1; val=$2`.

you can also solve this with ruby :

```
ruby -ne 'puts "%05d:%s" % $_.split(":")' input.txt
```

or perl

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+):/sprintf "%05d:", $1/e' input.txt
```

output

```
00001:line1
00014:line2
00135:line3
00015:line4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
 perl -lpe 's{^\d+}{sprintf "%05d", $&}e;' infile > outfile
```

To change the file in-place:

```
 perl -i.bak -lpe 's{^\d+}{sprintf "%05d", $&}e;' infile
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/e` : Evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as an expression in `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`

`^` : The beginning of the line.
`\d+` : One or more digits.  The match is captured into variable `$&`, which we use later inside `sprintf`.
`sprintf "%05d", $&` : returns a string where the digits captured in `$&` are padded with `0`s to give a number of length `5`.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)
- [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)

Answer (score 1):

A coreutils alternative:

```
paste -d: <(printf "%05d\n" $(cut -d: -f1 infile)) <(cut -d: -f2- infile)
```

Comment: If you make it `-f2-` instead of `-f2` then I think it'd work even if `line1`, etc. contained `:`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python script.
Here we are just splitting the line and zfilling the number to the required length.

```
def format_data(filename: str, int_length: int):
    new_lines = []
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        print("No file found!")
        return 1
    with open(filename, "r") as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj.readlines():
            try:
                pre, post = line.split(":")
                new_lines.append(f"{pre.zfill(int_length)}:post")
            except Exception:
                print(f"Some error")
                new_lines.append(line)
    write_filename = f"updated_{filename}"
    with open(write_filename, "w") as fileobj:
        fileobj.writelines([string + '\n' for string in new_lines])

    print(f"Saved updated file {write_filename}")
    return 0
```

Call the function with the filename and the total length of the number as needed

```
    format_data("sample.txt", 5)
```

The output file is written to `updated_<filename>` in the same directory.

Comment: Your script is not working properly! the output is `00001:post
00014:post
00135:post
00015:post`

Comment: Answers should solve the specific question being asked---the question asked about awk, so you should answer with awk instead of Python

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATED with streamlined version that retains chains of `:`, while preserving precision for any input length :***

```
echo '
2:line1
00123:line
::::::::line3
00000000000005923555555555555555555555555877777777:line9' |
```

---

```
gtee >( gcat -b >&2; ) | 

mawk '$!NF = substr("00000",__ = index($(NF += OFS = _),
                     ":"), (__ < 6) * 5) $_'    FS='^0+'
```

---

```
 1  2:line1
 2  00123:line2
 3  ::::::::line3
 4  00000000000005923555555555555555555555555877777777:line9
00002:line1
00123:line2
00000::::::::line3
5923555555555555555555555555877777777:line9
```

======================================================

It should be split into 3 scenarios :

> skip the sub-strings if it's already perfectly 5

---

> Zero trim the leading excess if it's longer, but in a precision preserving manner.

---

> pad to 5 when it's shorter

```
echo '
1:line1
14:line2
135:line3
15:line4
00000003523532:line5' |
```

---

```
 mawk '{ gsub(/::+/, ":") } ! (_ = 6-index($__, ":")) || 
       $!NF = _<-_ ? substr($__, match($__, /[^0]*.....:/)) \
                   : sprintf("%.*d",_,__) $__'
```

---

```
00001:line1
00014:line2
00135:line3
00015:line4
3523532:line5
```

> - Solutions utilizing `%05d` perform both a string-to-num then another num-to-string conversion when neither is needed,

Using `%05d` for longer inputs risk altering the input itself ::

```
echo '9992315351235323253252317:line9' |
```

---

```
gawk '{p=index($0,":"); printf "%05d%s\n", substr($0,1,p-1), substr($0,p)}'
```

---

```
               |
9992315351235322445824000:line9 
               |->
9992315351235323253252317:line9
               |
```

All digits at or to the right of the marked line has been corrupted by `%05d`. `bigint` certainly can mitigate this risk, but why require risk mitigation when there weren't any to begin with ?

Answer (score 0):

Error in you code is that your print FNR equivalent to Number of Record and $0 (all field). If you set the Field separator (-F=":") field $1 are valued that add zeros, and $2 is the second field with line value.
Thus print $1 (to add zero with %05d) into printf statment and $2(line value)

```
 awk -F"\:" '{printf "%05d:%s\n", $1, $2}' file
```

add "\" for string with regular expression ":"

Comment: if `line1`, etc. contained `:`s not working correctly !